# Are weapons with more damage purely better than ones with less damage?

Tags: fallout-shelter

In fallout shelter are weapons with higher damage better than weapons with lower damage?

E.g. is the common Rusty Laser Pistol (Dam 7) better than the legendary Lone Wanderer (Dam 2-7)?

E.g. Is the rare Hardened BB Gun (Dam 0-4) worse than the common Rusty Sawed-Off Shotgun (Dam 6)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, weapons with higher damage are better than weapons with lower damage when you are fighting radroaches or raiders. However, the legendary and rare weapons can be sold for a MUCH higher price. So they are worth more, but that doesn't mean that they are better as far as damage goes.

[This](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_Shelter_weapons) may help you.

Comment: Yep! No rate of fire you have to look out for or other factors, just pure damage.

Comment: Some weapons are AOE. How is damage calculated here? In order for "weapons with higher damage are better" to always be true the damage needs to be spread out among all enemies. For example 20 damage against 5 enemies does 4 damage each, against 2 enemies it does 10 damage each. However, **if this is true it's very counter-intuitive and should be clearly stated in the answer.** Otherwise there's a trade off in situations - for example Gatling laser vs. Missile launcher.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the weapons with the higher damage. The uniqueness is worthless, just take a look at it for the sale.

If you have two weapons, one with 7 damage and one with 6-8 damage. I normally take the 7 damage, as the damage is constant. The chance for dealing 8 damage is as high as the chance to get a low damage of 6.

Just sell your smaller weapons right a way. Give everyone the best weapons you have. Maybe hold 1-2 in your stock in case you get new dwellers. Everything else which is under your "current weapon standard" can be sold right away to save space in your stocks.

Answer (score 2):

The Fat Man Series of weapons damage all attackers in a room.  I haven't had that experience with the Fat Man in my own vault, but the MIRV will do up to 27 points of damage to all attackers in a room when on quest.