# Are Certain Fallout Shelter Enemies More Susceptible to Certain Weapon-Types?

Tags: fallout-shelter

At first I had hoped [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/281800/fallout-shelter-weapon-types-do-they-matter) was the same one I was asking, but it was asking specifically about the weapons' damage (i.e. Fat Man doing AoE damage versus other types of damage), rather than weapons' affect on various types of enemies. [This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/224996/are-weapons-with-more-damage-purely-better-than-ones-with-less-damage) ran in the same vein, again comparing among weapons rather than matching weapon-type to enemy-type. My question is more similar to the Pokemon franchise, where a fire-type pokemon is more susceptible to water-type attacks: **Do certain enemies have certain kinds of weaknesses to specific weapon-types such as energy, melee, or heavy weapons?**

I did check the wiki to see if I could find an answer, but unfortunately I did not. The [weapons article](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_Shelter_weapons) was helpful for comparing weapon damages across the board, but did not answer one way or the other concerning types. I also looked at the [creatures page](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_Shelter_creatures) and the [quests page](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_Shelter_quests), but saw nothing concerning damage received by enemies from weapons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No.

"Damage Type" is not a thing in Fallout shelter. The only comparison is damage/fire rate/AoE vs Single target. Since Deathclaws are fast, high damage automatic/burst fire weapons are your best bet, since you're likely only going to get one "round" of attacks off, before they move to the next room.